# "cpprest100_1_1.dll is missing" occurred after building. What are the possible causes for this to show?

Tags: c++, dll, sdk, server

My program calls the cpprest100_1_1.lib but there's no one who calls .dll file. I tried editing the configuration/linker and put the file directory of cpprest100_1_1.lib but still the error shows upon building.

[image: This is the image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this was long time ago but I already solved this issue. The following steps are the process on how I fix it:

1. I downloaded and installed the cpp rest.
2. Go to the project properties and in the **Build Events > Post-Build Event**, I included a commands which copies the cpp rest lib from the installed folder to the project folder/destination where you include your libraries in your project.

So basically, the cpp rest file is missing that's why my program is having an issue.

I hope this helps and message me if you have any questions. :)